# How to calculate the file count in multiple zipped folders?

Tags: vba, excel

> The below query does the job of counting file names within multiple unzipped folders, but I want to modify the query in such a way that it also includes the zipped folders and calculates the filename count in those folders as well.

```
Sub count()

    Range("B2").Value = getFileCount("\\hhhhh\ttttttt\kkkkkk")
    Range("B3").Value = getFileCount("\\gggggg\xxxxxx\yyyyyyy")

    End Sub



    Function getFileCount(localRoot, Optional fld, Optional count As Long) As Long
        Dim fso, f, baseFolder, subFolder, ftpFile, i

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

        If IsMissing(fld) Then
            Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot)
        Else
            Set baseFolder = fld
        End If

        count = count + baseFolder.Files.count

        For Each subFolder In baseFolder.SubFolders
            getFileCount localRoot, subFolder, count
        Next

        getFileCount = count
    End Function
```

> Please let me know if you have any questions or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a condition when the extension of the file is `.zip` it should consider that as a folder and count the items in it. It can be done with a `Shell` function called `NameSpace` that gets a string and changes it to a `Folder` object. Then you can use the same trick you have used to count thefiles inside the zip file. Note that zip files themselves will be counted, if you want to exclude them, then you have to modify the code block that counts zipfiles contents:

```
Option Explicit

Sub count()
    Debug.Print getFileCount("\\hhhhh\ttttttt\kkkkkk")
End Sub


Function getFileCount(localRoot, Optional fld, Optional count As Long) As Long
    Dim FileInFolder, x, sh, fileInZip, ZipFile, aFile, fso, f, baseFolder, subFolder, ftpFile, i

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    If IsMissing(fld) Then
        Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot)
    Else
        Set baseFolder = fld
    End If

    count = count + baseFolder.Files.count

    For Each subFolder In baseFolder.SubFolders
        'Count files inside the zip files
        For Each FileInFolder In subFolder.Files
            If Right(FileInFolder.Name, 4) = ".zip" Then

                Set ZipFile = sh.Namespace(FileInFolder.Path)
                count = count + ZipFile.items.count
            End If
        Next FileInFolder

        'Count all files
        getFileCount localRoot, subFolder, count
    Next

    getFileCount = count
End Function
```

Comment: @lbo I posted my full code, Please let me know if you're looking for something specific. Also, after including the code you've posted into my code's getfilecount function, there seems to be an "object required" error popping up. Please let me know what to do to resolve that.

Comment: @sat I changed the code as per your request if it worked please check the answer as approved and upvote it

Comment: I believe this code will work, will get back to you if I am having any issue. Thanks.

Comment: @lbo the updated code is running without any errors but isn't showing any result or output on the excel sheet.

Comment: @sat I changed your original code, you can change it back and it will print the result in cell B2

Comment: @sat use this line again and it will print `Range("B2").Value = getFileCount("\\hhhhh\ttttttt\kkkkkk")`

Comment: I did that "Range("B2").Value" change just now, but it doesn't count the files inside the zip folder, instead it counts zip folder as one file.

Comment: @sat double check that your zip files extension is not uppercase. If they are `.zip` and not `.ZIP` then it should. I ran the sub on my side and it did count the contents too.

Comment: @lbo .zip is in small case, so that's not the problem, but the error I am getting right now is "path not found", when I debugged the code it shows that there is something wrong with a line in the code "Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot)"

Comment: @sat your path  "\\hhhhh\ttttttt\kkkkkk" is just not found. Just simply copy and paste the path from windows explorer, or at least try with a simple path on your pc and not the network path.

Comment: @sat also, try localRoot with and without "\" at the end of it

Comment: @lbo Sorry , but I am actually trying to access a network path in this case. I believe that is the reason why this code isn't working for me. Can this code be tweaked to do the same job for network folders ?

Comment: @sat that line of code is the same line you had, and it should work as it worked before. Your address is somehow broken. If you can explore it with windows then the address is accessible. Also, by browsing the original folder make sure that you are connected to the network

Comment: @sat what is the folder address?

Comment: \\dzmjj6\source\Internal\Files - is the network folder address. Can you please let me know the updated code for network path ?

Comment: @sat was your original code working at all with this address?

Comment: My original code was only working at this address in counting the file names within multiple unzipped folders and counting a single zip folder as a single file, but didn't work in counting files inside the zip file.

Comment: FYI, The folder I am targeting has 9 zip files and each zip file has multiple files inside. But using my original code I could only capture the count of zip files, which is 9 in this case, but not the total number of files inside all 9 zip files.

Comment: anyways no problem, I don't want to waste your time anymore. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Another solution is to pick the localRoot. Make localRoot optional and then use the same block that is used to browse to select fld. I am sure that it is more reliable to choose the correct address